# Checking argument names inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, callback, arguments, identifier

Is there a way in javascript to check an arguments identifier name inside a function ??? for example:

```
 var config = function(callback){
     if(callback.definedArgumentName == 'argumentName') //do something
 };

 config(function(argumentName){
     //do something
 });
```

I am asking if there is something that can replace -callback.definedArgumentName- in this example.

Comment: Not a simple way, but [you can convert](http://jsfiddle.net/ydcqa3vo/2/) `callback` to a string, and retrieve argument names from it.

Comment: Why in the world are you trying to do this?  This sounds like a horrible hack that should probably be solved some other way.  What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: i am trying to understand how in angularJs they know the srvices provided in the function defenition only by the parameters name in the function defenition

Comment: i mean for example myApp.controller('name',function($scope,myService){});

Answer (score 0):

So i posted this question because i wondered how in AngularJs they recognize the order of the services you passed to a controller, and the names of the controllers you specified in the controller defenition.

Teemu's answer may be correct, i tried he's advice and evidently its not hard to do you just need some functionality. i have made an example:

```
var services = {
                '$scope': 'this is the scope service. ',
                 'myService' : 'this is your own service.'
               };

function controller(callback){
  var args = callback.toString().split('(');
  args.splice(0,1);
  args = args.join().split(')');
  args.splice(1,args.length-1);
  args = args.join();
  argNames = args.split(',');
  callback(services[argNames[0]],services[argNames[1]])
}

controller(function($scope,myService){
     console.log(services.$scope,services.myService)
});
```